# How i can check internet connection? android

Tags: java, android

i write func to chek internet conection, but i get Exeption `java.lang.SecurityException` in this stitch `NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();`

```
public static boolean isOnline()
{
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) MainActivity.sContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: added permission in android manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already added the permission to check the network status to you Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```